# Display the pdf file on the site

Tags: javascript, php, file, pdf, display

I want to know how to view a pdf file on the site without downloading it on the server.
I designed a site that allows the subscribers to read books in PDF format but I do not want the file to be uploaded to the server every time.
  What I want is how to read the file inside the site without uploading it to the server.
What I mean is that the person presses the button and selects the file from his computer and then starts reading directly without uploading it.
thanks guys.

Comment: most of the browser like chrome , firefox can be used as pdf reader . No need to go to a  website for reading a pdf

Comment: i know that Mr Monirul Alom Al-Amin

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a PDF with the following tag:

```
<embed src="files/Brochure.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px" />
```

the src tag inside embed can also be an url for a PDF on an external server.

Hope that helps.

Comment: McBoman What I want is how to read the file by the subscribers inside the site without uploading it to the server. thanks.